# Optimize Huffman Table symbol retrieval (Sequential and Progressive JPEG)

Tags: c#, optimization

Is there any further optimization that I can do to the below LINQ query where you can see that I traded

```
HuffmanTable.SymbolObject[] objects = hTable.Symbols.Where(x => x.Bits == i + 1).ToArray();
```

for

```
var objects = hTable.Symbols.Where(x => x.Bits == i + 1);
```

I'm unsure what else I could do to speed up the Huffman code lookup.

It takes about 1.157 second to process a 10 scan progressive 707x707 JPEG in Release, and right at 4 seconds for a 1920x1080 jpeg. GetNextSymbol is the biggest bottleneck in the code.

```
    HuffmanTable.SymbolObject GetNextSymbol(BitReader b, HuffmanTable hTable) {
        b.LastPositionBeforeGetSymbol = b.Position;
        uint currentCode = 0;
        for (uint i = 0; i < 16; ++i) {
            var c = b.ReadBit();
            if (c == null)
            {
                return new HuffmanTable.SymbolObject()
                {
                    Symbol = (int)currentCode,
                    Code = 0,
                    CodeString = null
                };
                //return null;
            }
            int bit = c.ValueByte;
            if (bit == -1) {
                return null;
            }
            currentCode = (uint)((currentCode << 1) | (uint)bit);

            //HuffmanTable.SymbolObject[] objects = hTable.Symbols.Where(x => x.Bits == i + 1).ToArray();
            var objects = hTable.Symbols.Where(x => x.Bits == i + 1);
            int j = 0;
            foreach(var obj in objects)
            {
                if (currentCode == obj.Code)
                {
                    return obj;
                }
            }
        }
        Console.WriteLine("*** COULD NOT FIND CODE *** {0}:{1}", currentCode, Convert.ToString(currentCode, 2));
        return null;
    }
```

Comment: Not that it's relevant to performance, but you could just have something like  `var found = hTable.Symbols.FirstOrDefault(x => x.Bits == i + 1 && x.Code == currentCode);`

Comment: That worked, thank you. I had to make an addition of if (result != null) return result; after the FirstOrDefault call or else I would run into problems because of the for loop. Found a few nested bottlenecks in the BitReader, it's a custom class I made for jpeg/gif/mp3, and picked up some more optimizations.

Comment: Is `hTable.Symbols` sorted? You could also do some stuff where you store the index to begin from if you don't find what you're looking for.

Comment: The hTable.Symbols (Huffman table) naturally sorts based on the bits it's decoding. So if the table had a 1 bit entry of 0, the rest of the entries in the table must start with a 1, on up to 16 bits, it's a fairly lean table according to the jpeg spec. The problem is I store all of the bits of encoded data of each jpeg scan as a list of bits (boolean), and as you call ReadBit() it increments Position until it reaches Length (EOF of list). So with each run underneath I need to get Bits[Position], which is maybe the tricky part.

Comment: I'll update as I can with some code from the BitReader class I made. I wanted flexibility to be able to traverse backwards in the stored list, but it might be faster as a Queue<T> instead of List<T> so that as I find codes I don't worry about the position but rather the remainder of bits, or maybe an optional switch between the two in the constructor.